# Basic IF Statement question -probably right in front of me

Tags: excel, if-statement, formula

Sorry i know this is super basic but i didn't know where else to ask and i really feel like the answer is right in front of me...

I have a spreadsheet which im going to use to log PAT test results. When i select the test type from a drop down it changes the standards and thresholds in the bit below and will tell me if each test passes or fails. It uses several vlookups and relative references - so far no VBA. Looking at [this photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z7L5t.png). What I'm trying to do is get the formula in cell I13 to read the symbol in F13 and use that in the formula rather than typing the symbol directly into the formula as its going to change when i change the Class Type option.

So far ive gotten to this (has a blank IF to start with to keep it neat:

=IF(H13="","",IF((**H13&F13&(VALUE(G13))**),"PASS","FAIL"))

The bit in bold is where the issue is. When i run the evaluate formula it boils the bold bit down to "0.01>2" which is correct however it then wont read that in the larger IF statement - i think its the quotation marks. So i think it needs another function to allow the IF statement to read that as the logical test rather than a text string.

I've tried VALUE, FORMULATEXT, NUMBERTEXT, all the ones that might be close to what I'm trying to do but 100% stumped now. Always bring sup the #VALUE Error.

Appreciate any advice? TIA

Answer (score 0):

There is no built-in function for that. You need either a VBA function or the old EVALUATE XLM function (which you can't use directly in a cell, it has to be in a defined name). Sample UDF:

```
Function EvaluateFormulaString(FormulaString as string)
   EvaluateFormulaString = application.evaluate(formulastring)
End Function
```

then your formula would become:

```
=IF(H13="","",IF(EvaluateFormulaString(H13&F13&(VALUE(G13))),"PASS","FAIL"))
```

Comment: Popped that in and getting a #NAME error for the EvaluateFormulaString. I put it in an empty VBA window - was that correct?

Comment: It needs to be in a normal module (which you'll have to add using the Insert menu in the VB Editor) not in a worksheet or ThisWorkbook module.

Comment: Ahhh that did it! Thanks so much for your help been driving me crazy!